# Build C project on CentOS 7, the linker can't use -ldl , -lc

Tags: linux, linker, glibc

### the issue

I started a C project on my local Ubuntu machine. After I completed the first version(the building is ok), I decided to upload the code to a server which runs a CentOS 7 to implement more features.
The code and the makefiles are the same on both sides.
But the code building on the remote shows the error as follows:

`/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -ldl
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lc
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status`

### building tools and environment

- OS:  centos7
- toolchain : gcc

### What I tried to fix this

- `yum install glibc-devel`

But it did not work.
How should I fix this?

### Edit , I got a workaround

I found the makefile I wrote a week ago is a little bit strange on LDFLAGS,

`LDFLAGS += -L$(LIBPATH) 
LDFLAGS += -static -lxxx -lyyy -ldl`

xxx and yyy is the static library name I need to link.

I modified the makefile to 

`LDFLAGS += -L$(LIBPATH) 
LDFLAGS +=  -l:libxxx.a -l:libyyy.a -ldl`

Now it works fine.

Comment: Link with `gcc`, not with `ld`. And show your compile and linking commands (preferably with some [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), so show some source code) so **edit your question** to improve it.

Comment: You are missing Dynamic Loader Function Interfaces i.e. `libdl` on CentOS.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`-static` requires the `glibc-static` package, not just `glibc-devel`.  But static linking has many limitations (particularly in combination with `dlopen`), and you should avoid it if at all possible.  (It is explicitly unsupported on Red Hat Enterprise Linux.)